# Spaces between words

Tags: formatting

I have this piece of code and I'm getting a really weird formatation.

```
\newpage
\section{Modelo Relacional}

Acidente(\underline{acidenteID}, data, responsavel, custo, $veiculoID \rightarrow Veiculo$, $tipoAcidenteID \rightarrow tipoAcidente$)
Cliente(\underline{clienteID}, nome, NIF, morada, telefone, email, $localidadeID\rightarrow Localidade$)\linebreak
Cobertura(\underline{coberturaID}, nome)\linebreak
Contrato(\underline{contratoID}, nome, preço, dataInicio, dataFim, valorFranquia, $tipoSeguroID\rightarrow tipoDeSeguro$, $veiculoID\rightarrow Veiculo$) \linebreak
Extras(\underline{extrasID}, nome)\linebreak
TipoDeSeguroCobertura(coberturaID, tipoDeSeguroID)\linebreak
VeiculoExtras(extrasID, veiculoID)\linebreak
Localidade(\underline{localidadeID}, nome, codPostal)\linebreak
Marca(\underline{marcaID}, nome)\linebreak
Modelo(\underline{modeloID}, nome, anoProducao, peso, consumo, cilindrada,  $modeloID\rightarrow Modelo$, $marcaID\rightarrow Marca$)\linebreak
Pagamento(\underline{pagamentoID}, dataPagamento, montante, $contratoID\rightarrow Contrato$)\linebreak
Proprietario(\underline{proprietarioID}, proprietario, $clienteID\rightarrow Cliente$, $contratoID\rightarrow Contrato$)\linebreak
TipoAcidente(\underline{tipoAcidenteID}, nome, descricaoAcidente)\linebreak
tipoDeSeguro(\underline{tipoDeSeguroID}, nome)\linebreak
Veiculo(\underline{veiculoID}, matricula, nomeMatricula, mesMatricula, chassi, $modeloID\rightarrow Modelo$)
```

[image]

how do I get rid of those spaces?

Best regards

Comment: Not using `\linebreak` but an empty line between to entries? The `\underline{...}` does not look really nice

Comment: This should be rather typeset in `tabular`, in my point of view

Answer (score 2):

By default, `\linebreak` ends the current line but does not create a new paragraph. The lines of paragraphs are justified, so the word spacing is stretched to make the lines filling the text width.

You can either replace the `\linebreak` command by `\par` or simply add a blank line between each of the current lines. You can also  create a list or a table. It really depends on the data you want to present.

Answer (score 2):

`\linebreak` stretches the horizontal space too much, leading to this weird void spacings in between.

Use empty lines or a `\par` instead.

I don't recommend the usage of `\underline{...}` here and the whole setup should be done in a `tabular` etc rather than inline.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}


\begin{document}

\section{Modelo Relacional}

\parindent=0em

Acidente(\underline{acidenteID}, data, responsavel, custo, $veiculoID \rightarrow Veiculo$, $tipoAcidenteID \rightarrow tipoAcidente$)

Cliente(\underline{clienteID}, nome, NIF, morada, telefone, email, $localidadeID\rightarrow Localidade$)

Cobertura(\underline{coberturaID}, nome)

Contrato(\underline{contratoID}, nome, preço, dataInicio, dataFim, valorFranquia, $tipoSeguroID\rightarrow tipoDeSeguro$, $veiculoID\rightarrow Veiculo$) 

Extras(\underline{extrasID}, nome)

TipoDeSeguroCobertura(coberturaID, tipoDeSeguroID)

VeiculoExtras(extrasID, veiculoID)

Localidade(\underline{localidadeID}, nome, codPostal)

Marca(\underline{marcaID}, nome)

Modelo(\underline{modeloID}, nome, anoProducao, peso, consumo, cilindrada,  $modeloID\rightarrow Modelo$, $marcaID\rightarrow Marca$)

Pagamento(\underline{pagamentoID}, dataPagamento, montante, $contratoID\rightarrow Contrato$)

Proprietario(\underline{proprietarioID}, proprietario, $clienteID\rightarrow Cliente$, $contratoID\rightarrow Contrato$)

TipoAcidente(\underline{tipoAcidenteID}, nome, descricaoAcidente)

tipoDeSeguro(\underline{tipoDeSeguroID}, nome)

Veiculo(\underline{veiculoID}, matricula, nomeMatricula, mesMatricula, chassi, $modeloID\rightarrow Modelo$)

\end{document}
```

Comment: I replaced the linebreaks for \\* and it seems to be working now. What can I use instead of \underline?

Comment: `\underlining` is taken to be bad typography, that's why I commented on it.

Comment: Yes. But how do I underline without \underline?

Comment: @Perseverance: Oh my -- I mean you should **not** underline at all ;-)

Comment: Oh, sorry, got you now. But it's part of the terminology of relational models. It represents the primary key :)